# Pandas drop duplicates is not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am building multiple dataframes from a SQL query that contains a lot of left joins which is producing a bunch of duplicate values. I am familiar with pd.drop_duplicates() as I use it regularly in my other scripts, however, I can't get this particular one to work.

I am trying to drop_duplicates on a subset of 2 columns. Here is my code:

```py
df = pd.read_sql("query")
index = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    index.append(i)

df['index'] = index
df.set_index([df['index']])

df2 = df.groupby(['SSN', 'client_name', 'Evaluation_Date']).substance_use_name.agg(' | '.join).reset_index()
df2.shape which equals (182,4)

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1, join='outer').drop_duplicates(keep=False)
df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['client_name', 'Evaluation_Date'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

df3 returns 791 rows of data... (which is the exact amount of rows that my original query returns). After the `drop_duplicates` method I expected to have only 190 rows of data, however, it only drops the duplicates to 301 rows. When I do `df3.to_excel(r'file_path.xlsx')` and remove duplicates manually by the same subset in Excel, it works just fine and gives me the 190 rows that I expect. I'm not sure why?

I noticed in other similar questions regarding this topic that pandas cannot drop duplicates if a date field is a dtype 'object' and that it must be changed to a datetime, however, my date field is already a datetime.

Data frame looks like this:

ID | substnace1 | substance2 | substance3 | substance4

01 | drug | null | null | null

01 | null | drug | null | null

01 | null | null | drug | null

01 | null | null | null | drug

02 | drug | null | null | null

so on and so forth. I want to merge the rows into one row so it looks like this:

ID | substnace1 | substance2 | substance3 | substance4

01 | drug | drug | drug | drug

02 | drug | drug | drug | drug

so on and so forth.. Does that make better sense?

Would anyone be able to help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: I am sure it will be more easy and faster to do it in MySql in your query than in pandas

Comment: My job requires me to use SQL server and unfortunately I don't have write access so I can only pull data from our database. All of the data manipulation has to be done through python since we are very limited in access to our database.

Comment: You are aware that with subset=['client_name', 'Evaluation_Date'] you only drop if both are true ? 
And for i in range(len(df)):
    index.append(i)

df['index'] = index
df.set_index([df['index']]) ? 
when a pandas index column normally is already a self increasing column ?

Comment: Then you can use SQL server & Tsql to make the right query to get the data without duplicates. You just need to use in your SELECT the DISTINCT/GROUP BY/WINDOW FUNCTION to make a good query that avoids duplicates

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear about what I mean by duplicates I apologize. For example: I have a record for one person that has 4 rows of data, I'm looking at a 4 different columns that contain the name of different substances and each column has a value for this instance. That's why I'm seeing 4 rows because this particular example has 4 substances on record. I want to merge the 4 rows into one row and have all of the substances in the same row. I'll continue my explanation in the next comment.

Comment: I have edited the post above to more clearly explain the problem.

Comment: If your example is correct, subset=['client_name', 'Evaluation_Date'] wil not work, as the both row must then be duplicates. Try df3.drop_duplicates(subset=['client_name'], keep='first).drop_duplicates(subset=['Evaluation_Date'], keep='first) . Or try merging on  id.